# Error: insertor is not a member of std

Tags: c++, stl, set-difference

I have a code like below:

```
#include<set>
#include<iterator>

some_func()
{
     std::set_difference(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(),s2.end(),std::insertor(myresult,myresult.begin()));
}
```

Its giving me an error:

```
Error: insertor is not a member of std.
```

Comment: Please format code with four spaces, backticks ` or using the button on the editor toolbar. I did it for you this time.

Answer (score 2):

That function is named [std::inserter](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/inserter/), not `std::insertor`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::inserter`, not `std::insertor`.